# mysql server does not start!

Tags: mysql, database, service

I had installed MySQL server 5.1.1 on my PC (windows 7 ultimate 32bit, CPU Dual core 2.60 MHz, 2.00 GB RAM) and it was up and running well, until last Wednesday I was forced to uninstall it, and now when I reinstall it,in the last level of creating server instance, when I press execute, It checks OK for 'prepare configuration' and 'write configuration file', but in 'start server' it faces an error and doesn't continue... and afterward when I try to start MySQL service manually from windows services, It says:
"Windows could not start MySQL service on local computer.
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly."
When I wanna check error log to see why? the data folder of mysql is empty! 
I tried everything:
port 3306 is open and no one is listening on it.
my firewall has mysql exception and I even disabled it.
i even tried new versions of mysql 5.1.2 it's the same.
What should I do... please guys! this is urgent.

Answer (score 2):

If your 'data' Directory is empty you already found the problem. It ain't supposed to empty, at least the 'mysql' Directory within and files are necessary so it can start.

Comment: Heh, well spotted! :) +1

Comment: thanks, but how can i fix it... the error is from installation and I don't know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the server's error log (`your_hostname.err`). You should find a detailed message there.

IIRC, 1067 is a missing data directory.

Comment: I fixed this empty folder somehow and now in .err files there is some errors:101110 15:23:12 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.    I ran mysql_upgrade but it's still the same and wth starting mysql server the error does not change

Comment: @Ehphan well, then fix the errors?

Comment: and there's also another error in the last line of error log and says: 101110 15:29:08 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist

Comment: @Ehphan You need certain tables in the data directory. They should have been installed automatically. You should find them and copy them over