# mysqld 5.6 service error 1067

Tags: windows, mysql, database, windows-service

Upon running this service

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56
```

I get this error

```
windows could not start mysql56 service of local computer
error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJDwB.png

---

However running just mysqld.exe runs OK
https://i.stack.imgur.com/935sb.png
But it won't accept my saved passwords and databases..

---

---

Similar question 
[mysql server does not start!](https://serverfault.com/questions/200840/mysql-server-does-not-start) 
suggests that it's a directory issue, I've checked all the directories and they are exactly what they should be like (i guess..) http:\i.imgur,com/t76KGR0.png (link: need 10+ reps)

---

Also, it was working just 10 days ago. I haven't messed with anything I can remember...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perror 1067
MySQL error code 1067 (ER_INVALID_DEFAULT): Invalid default value for '%-.192s'
```

Check your mysql log file and find out which parameter in your config is causing problems.